# Highlight search match in visible text

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an input which allows the user to filter table rows based on a search query. I want to highlight the match, but unfortunately it will currently highlight things that are not visible to the user.

Given a row like so;

```
<tr>
  <td>Row 1</td>
  <td>&#215; 4</td>
  <td><span class="tag1">Archived</span></td>
</tr>
```

The code to highlight the match (the code to actually filter the rows is separate), is as follows (`content` equals to the innerHTML of each `td`);

```
return String(content).replace(new RegExp("("+query+")", "gi"), '<em class="highlight">$1</em>');
```

This will unfortunately output something like so when `query == "1"`;

```
<tr>
  <td>Row <em class="highlight">1</em></td>
  <td>&#2<em class="highlight">1</em>5; 4</td>
  <td><span class="tag<em class="highlight">1</em>">Archived</span></td>
</tr>
```

The first cell will be as intended, but the HTML entity and tag in cells 2 and 3 will appear corrupted.

I've attempted to filter these out like so;

```
var strip_tags = String(content).replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
var convert_entities = $('<textarea />').html(strip_tags).text();
return convert_entities.replace(new RegExp("("+this.query+")", "gi"), '<em class="highlight">$1</em>');
```

However, this naturally will also strip tags from the output;

```
<tr>
  <td>Row <em class="highlight">1</em></td>
  <td>× 4</td>
  <td>Archived</td>
</tr>
```

In this case, cells 1 and 2 are as intended, but cell 3 has lost its `span` tag.

How do I highlight search matches in JavaScript so that HTML entities and tags are not taken into account, but also not deleted?

Comment: I would humbly suggest using Vue for this

Comment: The app is already in Vue, but I don't see how this functionality is specific to Vue... unless I've missed some feature?

Comment: It's nothing specific to vue. I just assumed you weren't using it and it's something you can just throw in. With vue you could have your entire table within an array and let the elements get highlighted whenever they match the search query.
Your current approach looks painful.

Comment: Each td has a `v-html` attribute which generates the content via a component method, which, together with some other logic, also includes the match highlighting, if the user is currently searching. The table indeed is an array, and the actual filtering itself happens with that (independently from this); this is only about visually highlighting the matches.

Comment: I may not fully understand what you want to do, but can you use a negated lookahead, of a form something like this? `/1(?!\w)/` It seems like you just want to match a number when it's by itself.

Comment: I doubt you should be using v-html for that. You could use a dynamic class and a couple v-ifs at most.

Vue gives you everything you need for a UI. If you are bringing JQuery in on top of it, rethink how you are approaching the problem.

Comment: I only introduced jQuery to convert the entities to characters, but that approach is not working, so it's probably going away.

Comment: @denmch The query == "1" in just the above example, the query could be anything.

Comment: @EmphramStavanger I know. I'm not offering a complete answer, but wondering if what you're trying to do is just match numbers in isolation, i.e., 1 and not 917, 123, &#215;, etc. If that's the case, it seems like it would pretty straightforward to work out the matching.